# React Native error: Super expression must either be null or a function

Tags: react-native, error-handling, android-emulator, runtime-error

I get the error when i trie to run this app on my Android Emulator. I changed "Component" to "React.Component" but then i get other Problems.
My versions of React, Node and JS are the newest.
The Problem is that im new and have this Code from a Viedo and he didnt got thet Mistake.

*Without React.Component:*

[image: Without React.Component]

*With React.Component:*

[image: With React.Component]

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StatusBar,
  Component,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#1e90ff" barStyle="light-content" />,
          <Text style={styles.login}>Login</Text>,
          <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Username" />,
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Password"
            secureTextEntry
          />
        <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.userBtn}>
            <text style={styles.btnText}>Login</text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.userBtn}>
            <text style={styles.btnText}>Text</text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#1e90ff',
  },
  login: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 35,
    margin: 10,
    color: '#fff',
  },
  input: {
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    height: 30,
  },
  btnContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: '90%',
  },
  userBtn: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 15,
    width: '40%',
    margin: 10,
  },
  btnText: {
    fontSize: 25,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#1e90ff',
  },
});
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

**1. TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function**

To fix this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

Then you can use

```
export default class App extends Component
```

**2. Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a  component**

To fix this remove `,` & change

```
<text style={styles.btnText}>Login</text>
```

to

```
<Text style={styles.btnText}>Login</Text>
```

**EDIT**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="#1e90ff" barStyle="light-content" />
        <Text style={styles.login}>Login</Text>
        <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Username" />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Password"
          secureTextEntry
        />
        <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.userBtn}>
            <Text style={styles.btnText}>Login</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.userBtn}>
            <Text style={styles.btnText}>Text</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: Thanks, but now i get a different error: Invarit Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component. This error is located at: RCTView(at App.js:18), App(at renderApplication.js: 40), RCTView(at AppContainer.js:101), RCTView(at AppContainer.js:119), in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39) Do you need anymore Information? Just tell me.

Comment: @JannikJanjan I added changes to the answer check that.

Comment: @JannikJanjan If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it